# In Python why are static class members read when the class has not been instantiated?

Tags: python, oop

I was a bit surprised to see the following behavior in Python. Is there a reason why classes that have not been called are opened and their static members read?

test_inheritance.py

```
import unittest
from tests.family import Parent

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testParent(self):
        bob = Parent()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

family.py

```
class Parent(object):
    CONSTANT = "Constant belonging to Parent"
    print("Parent {0}".format(CONSTANT))
    def __init__(self):
        print(">>__init_() Parent")

class Child(Parent):
    CONSTANT = "Constant belonging to Child"
    print("Child {0}".format(CONSTANT))
    def __init__(self):
        print(">>__init_() Child")

class Friend(object):
    CONSTANT = "Constant belonging to Friend"
    print("Friend {0}".format(CONSTANT))
    def __init__(self):
        print(">>__init_() Friend")
```

Output is:

Parent Constant belonging to Parent

Child Constant belonging to Child

Friend Constant belonging to Friend

__init_() Parent

Answer (score 2):

No [instances of `Parent`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) are instantiated (`Parent()`). However, a [class object](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) describing the `Parent` class is instantiated (`class Parent`). It will execute all class object initialisation statements and method definitions as it is being processed.

Comment: Parent was instantiated when I assigned bob to an instance of it, but yes this happened after the static members were accessed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking why static class members have values before the classes have been instantiated, it is because static members of a class exist essentially independently from the class. Since static members by definition aren't tied to an instance, why would they require an instance to exist before they do?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good reference for a detailed explanation of the process but from what I can gather:

On import class attribute references are added to the

```
class.__dict__
```

object for each class within the module (eg family.py).